# AttributeError: Node instance has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, attributes, instance

First I want to say that I searched for my problem but due to the nature of the problem + the code I have to work with I did not find a solution. Therefore here is my problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AlienTilesMain.py", line 28, in <module>
    goal = astar_search(prob, prob.h1)
  File "/home/chris/Desktop/search.py", line 274, in astar_search
    return best_first_graph_search(problem, lambda n: n.path_cost + h(n))
  File "/home/chris/Desktop/search.py", line 213, in best_first_graph_search
    frontier.append(node)
  File "/home/chris/Desktop/utils.py", line 738, in append
    bisect.insort(self.A, (self.f(item), item))
  File "/home/chris/Desktop/utils.py", line 612, in memoized_fn
    val = fn(obj, *args)
  File "/home/chris/Desktop/search.py", line 274, in <lambda>
    return best_first_graph_search(problem, lambda n: n.path_cost + h(n))
  File "/home/chris/Desktop/utils.py", line 612, in memoized_fn
    val = fn(obj, *args)
  File "/home/chris/Desktop/AlienTiles.py", line 57, in h1
   n = len(state[0])
AttributeError: Node instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

and my code is this one:

```
def h1(self, state):
    n = len(state[0])
.
.
return value
```

in my main file:

```
goal = astar_search(prob, prob.h1)
```

and here are the Problem, Node Class and A* :

```
class Problem(object):
    def __init__(self, initial, goal):
        """The constructor specifies the initial state, and possibly a goal
        state, if there is a unique goal.  Your subclass's constructor can add
        other arguments."""
        self.initial = initial; self.goal = goal

    def actions(self, state):
        """Return the actions that can be executed in the given
        state. The result would typically be a list, but if there are
        many actions, consider yielding them one at a time in an
        iterator, rather than building them all at once."""
        abstract

    def result(self, state, action):
        """Return the state that results from executing the given
        action in the given state. The action must be one of
        self.actions(state)."""
        abstract
class Node:
"""A node in a search tree. Contains a pointer to the parent (the node
that this is a successor of) and to the actual state for this node. Note
that if a state is arrived at by two paths, then there are two nodes with
the same state.  Also includes the action that got us to this state, and
the total path_cost (also known as g) to reach the node.  Other functions
may add an f and h value; see best_first_graph_search and astar_search for
an explanation of how the f and h values are handled. You will not need to
subclass this class."""

def __init__(self, state, parent=None, action=None, path_cost=0):
    "Create a search tree Node, derived from a parent by an action."
    update(self, state=state, parent=parent, action=action,
           path_cost=path_cost, depth=0)
    if parent:
        self.depth = parent.depth + 1

def __repr__(self):
    return "<Node %s>" % (self.state,)

def expand(self, problem):
    "List the nodes reachable in one step from this node."
    return [self.child_node(problem, action)
            for action in problem.actions(self.state)]

def child_node(self, problem, action):
    "Fig. 3.10"
    next = problem.result(self.state, action)
    return Node(next, self, action,
                problem.path_cost(self.path_cost, self.state, action, next))

def solution(self):
    "Return the sequence of actions to go from the root to this node."
    return [node.action for node in self.path()[1:]]

def path(self):
    "Return a list of nodes forming the path from the root to this node."
    node, path_back = self, []
    while node:
        path_back.append(node)
        node = node.parent
    return list(reversed(path_back))

def astar_search(problem, h=None):
    """A* search is best-first graph search with f(n) = g(n)+h(n).
    You need to specify the h function when you call astar_search, or
    else in your Problem subclass."""
    h = memoize(h or problem.h, 'h')
    return best_first_graph_search(problem, lambda n: n.path_cost + h(n))
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `Node`? If it doesn't define `def __getitem__(self, key):` then you can't use `node = Node(); node[key]`. `state` must be a `Node` to get this error.

Comment: state is a tuple of tuples actually because i need an "array" and i transform it to a list when necessary

Comment: The error message disagrees with you! Check what `state` is, using `print` or similar

Comment: I think jonrshape is right, the error you get seems to point out that state is not a tuple as you would like to have but rather a Node object that fails the `__getitem__` property. The `__getitem__` function is called on statements like var[item] and error is triggered by the line `n = len(state[0])` according to the trace.

Comment: yes you are right, state is a node, so there is a mistake in my code that transforms it into a Node, or it is normal and I have to handle it as such? sorry im asking this but this is a framework that has been given to me and i was told that i should not change anything

Comment: Not enough information to tell you that, sorry. Maybe try `len(state.solution)` or `len(state.path)`, depending on what you need?